# Admob / Adwhirl changes active activity?

Tags: android, admob, tabactivity, adwhirl

My problem is about Admob / Adwhirl and the activity that will become active when an ad is loaded.

I have a TabActivity and one of the tabs contains two views (two separate intents), on those two intents I fetch the onBackPressed to know if I have to switch between the views **in the current** tab. This all works fine, until I load the ads.

When I activate Admob / Adwhirl onBackPressed is triggered on the TabActivity itself and not on the intents inside the current tab.

Any idea on how to prevent / fix this?

Comment: I am having the same problem. This problem is occurring for me only after integrating the Admob ads. I too have a TabActivity with 4 tabs and each tab has 4 activities. After navigating through 3 activities in any of the tabs and back pressing instead of coming back to the previous activity (which used to occur before loading the ads) the app is exiting and the onDestroy() method of the MainTabActivity is getting called. Could you please let me know if you have found a solution to this?